# How to format view results in mvc3?

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, razor

I have List of checkbox in my view. it shows me in vertical format.
Like

a

b

c

d

...

But i want to format that in such a way that will look like.

a b c d

e f g h

i j k l

My code  looks like this

```
 @foreach (var item in Model)
  {
  <table>
      <tr>
         <td><input type="checkbox" id="@item.DataId" name="Data"/>@item.DataName</td>
      </tr>
  </table>
```

How can i format this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hoping you're not using the table for layout purposes ;)

Anyway this should do the trick, it's rough code, and could be polished but hopefully this will give you a good start

```
<table>
    <tr>
@{var rower = 0;}
    @foreach (var item in Model)
    {
        if (rower % 4 == 0 && rower != 0)
        {
            @:</tr>
            @:<tr>
        }
         <td><input type="checkbox" id="@item.DataId" name="Data"/>@item.DataName</td>
        rower++;
    }
    </tr>
</table>
```

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you need a list, not a table:

// You may to check here whether model contains any items

```
<ul>
@foreach (var item in Model)
{
   <li><input type="checkbox" id="@item.DataId" name="Data"/>@item.DataName</li>
}
</ul>
```

In your CSS you need to set display property of the list to `inline`